# Proof that $|z - w| \geq ||z| - |w||$ where $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm reading a book on complex analysis at the moment and the inequality $|z - w| \ge ||z| - |w||$ and I am specifically confused as to how the greater modulus sign appeared on the right-hand side as I can prove $|z + w| \le |z| + |w|$ and this inequality does not have the greater modulus sign on the right hand sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply a matter of renaming the variables.

Let $y = z+w$, then the triangle inequality becomes $|y| \leq |z| + |y-z|$, or $|y-z| \geq |y| - |z|$.

Changing the order of $y$ and $z$, we find $|y-z| \geq |z| - |y|$, thus $|y-z| \geq ||y| - |z||$.